# wrong-type-argument listp \357\273\277 when working with packages

Tags: debugging, package-repositories

I use Emacs 27.2 on Windows 10. Working with packages used to work, but now I am getting `Failed to download ‘gnu’ archive.`, when calling for instance `M-x package-refresh-contents`.
I tried `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, and in the call stack I see `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp \357\273\277)` So the BOM symbol is involved.

**Update 1**
I have confirmed that running `emacs -Q` makes the error go away. So then I have stripped my init file to contain only:

```lisp
(setq user-emacs-directory "C:/users/avpas/.emacs.d")

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d")
```

To clearify, my `HOME` is set to other than `C:/users/avpas`. At this point, the error persists, but goes away when I remove the first row `(setq user-emacs-directory "C:/users/avpas/.emacs.d")`.

Comment: Set `debug-on-error` to `t` and show the backtrace here.

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. If yes, provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem, starting from `emacs -Q`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I looked up to reset the Emacs's state, which is saved in .emacs.d directory (`user-emacs-directory`). I created a backup copy of that directory. Then I looked inside it, and the most suspicious looking file was `network-security.data`. I deleted it and restarted Emacs. Voila, the problem was gone.